# How can I remap function keys while ensuring that they retain their original functions?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, remapping, button-remapping

I would like to remap certain keys but ensure that they still retain their original functions with modifiers.

For example, I want to remap <kbd>F4</kbd> to `mute`, but I want <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to still close applications. Is this possible?

I am currently using [KeyTweak](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/keytweak.html), but after remapping <kbd>F4</kbd> to `mute`, even <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> just mutes volume.

*Edit: I'm running a PC with Windows 10 home. I have full admin rights.*

**EDIT (9 months later):**

I have recently purchased a laptop with a rather small keyboard. I don't have <kbd>home</kbd> or <kbd>end</kbd> keys. I'd like to remap the keyboard in the following manner:

- <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> retain their original functions.
- <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> or<kbd>]</kbd> enter curly brackets as they're supposed to.
- <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>]</kbd> work as <kbd>home</kbd> and <kbd>end</kbd> respectively.

I have been unable to find any solutions on the internet. If the solution is to run some sort of a script in the background, it must not be too resource intensive.

Comment: Maybe you've already tried this, and if so, I apologize, but have you tried using KeyTweak to explicitly map Alt+F4 (back) to "close application"?

Comment: @bjkeefe I don't think KeyTweak has the functionality to remap key combinations...

Comment: I have not tried it personally, but I've heard good things from friends about AutoHotKey.  (https://www.autohotkey.com/)  Following links, starting with "What is it?" on the home page, and then "Key Binds," it looks like you can use AHK to assign function keys without changing the Alt+... meaning.  Lots of help with AHK available through Googling, too.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I *think* autohotkey will do this. It'd look something similar to the following:

```
F4
If GetKeyState("LAlt", "P")
    Send +{CloseWindow}
Else
    Send {Mute}
Return
```